# How to process access log using python multiprocessing library?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multiprocessing

I have to parse 30 days access logs from the server based on client IP and accessed hosts and need to know top 10 accessed sites. The log file will be around 10-20 GB in size which takes lots of time for single threaded execution of script. Initially, I wrote a script which was working fine but it is taking a lot of time to due to large log file size. Then I tried to implement multiprocessing library for parallel processing but it  is not working. It seems implementation of multiprocessing is repeating tasks instead of doing parallel processing. Not sure, what is wrong in the code. Can some one please help on this? Thank you so much in advance for your help.

Code:

```
  from datetime import datetime, timedelta
  import commands
  import os
  import string
  import sys
  import multiprocessing


  def ipauth (slave_list, static_ip_list):

      file_record = open('/home/access/top10_domain_accessed/logs/combined_log.txt', 'a')
      count = 1
      while (count <=30):
      Nth_days = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=count)
      date = Nth_days.strftime("%Y%m%d")
      yr_month = Nth_days.strftime("%Y/%m")
      file_name = 'local2' + '.' + date
      with open(slave_list) as file:
        for line in file:
            string = line.split()
            slave = string[0]
            proxy = string[1]
            log_path = "/LOGS/%s/%s" %(slave, yr_month)

            try:
               os.path.exists(log_path)
               file_read = os.path.join(log_path, file_name)
               with open(file_read) as log:
                     for log_line in log:
                        log_line = log_line.strip()
                        if proxy in log_line:
                           file_record.write(log_line + '\n')
            except IOError:
               pass

        count = count + 1
        file_log = open('/home/access/top10_domain_accessed/logs/ipauth_logs.txt', 'a')
        with open(static_ip_list) as ip:
             for line in ip:
                with open('/home/access/top10_domain_accessed/logs/combined_log.txt','r') as f:
             for content in f:
                log_split = content.split()
                client_ip = log_split[7]
                if client_ip in line:
                   content = str(content).strip()
                   file_log.write(content + '\n')

         return

   if __name__ == '__main__':
        slave_list = sys.argv[1]
        static_ip_list = sys.argv[2]
        jobs = []
        for i in range(5):
           p = multiprocessing.Process(target=ipauth, args=(slave_list, static_ip_list))
           jobs.append(p)
           p.start()
           p.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE AFTER CONVERSATION WITH OP, PLEASE SEE COMMENTS**

My take: Split the file into smaller chunks and use a process pool to work on those chunks:

```
import multiprocessing

def chunk_of_lines(fp, n):
    # read n lines from file
    # then yield
    pass

def process(lines):
    pass # do stuff to a file

p = multiprocessing.Pool()
fp = open(slave_list)
for f in chunk_of_lines(fp,10):
    p.apply_async(process, [f,static_ip_list])
p.close()
p.join() # Wait for all child processes to close.
```

There are many ways to implement the `chunk_of_lines` method, you could iterate over the file lines using a simple `for` or do something more advance like call `fp.read()`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But here I am passing only file path as argument in the function so slave_list is not iterable thing. Actually both slave_list and static_ip_list are file path. I tried passing slave_list instead of f in apply_async function and I see there are multiple process running but I believe all the processes are doing operation in the same data. So, it's kind of repeated task. Any suggestion? Thanks.